# PHP add value in the last foreach loop

Tags: php

I want to add some extra values by using foreach loop.

```
foreach($a as $b) {
echo $b; // this will print 1 to 6 
}
```

Now I want to edit last item with custom text
and print like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
6 this is last.
```

how can i do this? Please help I am new in PHP.

Comment: `if (b == 6)` for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `end` of array

```
<?php
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
foreach($a as $b) {
echo $b; // this will print 1 to 6 
if($b == end($a))
  echo "this is last.";
echo "<br>";
}
```

**EDIT**
as @ alexandr comment if you have same value you can do it with key

```
<?php
$a = array(6,1,2,3,4,5,6);
end($a);         // move the internal pointer to the end of the array
$last_key = key($a);
foreach($a as $key=>$b) {
echo $b; // this will print 1 to 6 
if($key == $last_key)
  echo "this is last.";
echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I do it with unknown number of array?

Comment: Please note, it will not work for arrays like: `[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]`

Comment: @anamahmed what do you mean by `unknown number of array`?

Comment: Thanks brother. Its worked. I didn't understand it in first.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare inc variable, and use with array count

```
<?php
//$b is your array
$i=1;
foreach($a as $b) {
if(count($a)==$i){
    echo $b; // this is last    
}
$i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$last = count($a) - 1;
foreach($a as $k => $b) {
echo $b; // this will print 1 to 6 
if($k == $last)
    echo "this is last.";
echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use count, the thats way you get the size and you can use in a condicional like if

```
$size=count($a);

foreach($a as $b) {

      if ($b==$size)
      {
          echo $b. "This is the last"; // this will print 6 and text
      }
     else
     {
        echo $b; // this will print 1 to 5 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_slice which is a good way to slice up an array.
You can set it to get the last item(s) with negative numbers.

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

$last = array_slice($arr, -1, 1)[0]; // 6
$other = array_slice($arr, 0, -1); // [1,2,3,4,5]

foreach($other as $item){
    echo $item;
}

echo $last . " this is the last";
```